# from dataframe to json

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Hi how are things? I have a dataframe, which looks like a recursive table, my idea is to be able to transform it to a json (in a mamushka way). Im using python

my example:

Datafame:

| id | name | relations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | config | 0 |
| 2 | buttons | 1 |
| 3 | accept | 2 |
| 4 | delete | 2 |
| 5 | descripton | 1 |
| 6 | title | 1 |
| 7 | juan | 0 |

and the json that i whant is

```
[{
"id":"1"
"name":"config",
"relations":
  [{
    "id":"2"
    "name":"buttons"
    "relations":[{
        "id":"3"
        "name":"accept"
         },
        {
         "id":"4",
        "name":"delete"
        }],
    },
   {
   "id":"5"
    "name":"descripton",
    "relations":[]
   },
   "id":"6"
   "name":"title",
   "relations":[]
  }],
"id":"7",
"name":"juan",
"relations":[] 
}]
```

As you will see, in the column "relation", you can see that it joins with its parents (id)

Comment: Your json example is not right. Please check it again. `id:1` and `id:7` are within same dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to assemble a tree from a pandas DataFrame, but this task seemed interesting to me from the point of view of algorithms. I will give my solution.

To begin with, fill the list of the `df_list` tree with elements from the root of the tree (relations == 0).

```py
df_list = [{'id': row.id, 'name': row['name']} for _, row in df[df['relations'] == 0].iterrows()]
```

To collect the tree, you will need a recursive search function. I wrote it quickly, I'm sure it can be done more efficiently if necessary:

```py
def find_relations_reqursion(id):
    
    # We find the child elements and create a list of them
    childs = df[df['relations'] == id]
    childs_list = []
    
    for _, row in childs.iterrows():
        # If a child element does not have its own child elements, we do not collect its relations.
        if df[df['relations'] == row.id].shape[0] == 0:
            childs_list.append({
                'id': row.id,
                'name': row['name']
            })
        # Otherwise, we find its child elements using recursion
        else:
            childs_list.append({
                'id': row.id,
                'name': row['name'],
                'relations': find_relations_reqursion(row.id)
            })
            
    return childs_list
```

Next, we need to collect child elements for the root objects:

```py
for obj in df_list:
    if df[df['relations'] == obj['id']].shape[0] != 0:
        obj['relations'] = find_relations_reqursion(obj['id'])
```

At the end, it remains only to pack the list into a json string:

```py
import json
result = json.dumps(df_list)
```

There is a nuance. In your example, some of the elements that do not have children do not have the `relations` key, and others contain empty arrays in it. I do not know by what rule this is selected, so I just do not create a key.